How to conditionally disable a Spring microservice and prevent entity table creation based on a configuration property?
I have Spring microservice project:
This is the project structure:
- Project
      - src
        - main
          - java
            -- com.example
                -- Microservice1
                -- Microservice2
                    -controller
                    -service
                    -repository
                    -entity
                    -dto
                    -mapper
                -- Microservice3
                - MainClass.java
            
          - resources
          - application.yml
          
      - build.gradle

I want to disable Microservice 2 based on a condition like true or false:

The table should not be created in the database for Microservice 2
Beans in controller, service, repository should not be created
if the condition is true all the beans of Microservice 2 and table in DB should be created, if false all the beans of Microservice 2 and table in DB should not be created.

I have tried using @ConditionalOnExpression for the controller, service, repository and the beans are not created
//UserController

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@ConditionalOnExpression("${user.enabled}")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User createdUser = userService.createUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

The above approach is not working for the entity class, and the table is  created in the database.
Below is the entity class:
//User Entity
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users_table")
@ConditionalOnExpression("${user.enabled}")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    
}

Below is my application.properties file
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.sql.init.mode=always

# H2 DATABASE
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true

order.enabled=false

server.port=9091


The @ConditionalOnExpression (and an alternative @Profile) annotations work only with beans. Entity class is not a bean. That's why the table will be created at startup.
Solution 1
Don't let JPA create the database tables. Use SQL script instead. You can have different scripts for different profiles.
Solution 2
Use a proper microservice architecture and put each microservice to a separate project or module.
